# How to have highly available Moodle in Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, moodle, high-availability, bitnami, kubernetes-pvc

Want to set up highly available Moodle in K8s (on-prem). I'm using Bitnami Moodle with helm charts.

After a successful Moodle installation, it becomes work. But when a K8s node down, Moodle web page displays/reverts/redirects to the Moodle installation web page. It's like a loop.

Persistence storage is rook-ceph. Moodle PVC is ReadriteMany where Mysql is ReadWriteOnce.

The following command was used to deploy Moodle.

```
helm install moodle --set persistence.accessMode=ReadWriteMany,allowEmptyPassword=false,moodlePassword=Moodle123,mariadb.architecture=replication bitnami/moodle
```

Any help on this is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately high availability is not supported by the Bitnami Helm chart for Moodle, as it is not prepared to deal with replicas (as it currently requires an initialization script to complete successfully, not feasible for multiple nodes). I'd recommend you to either try another solution or to open a GitHub issue in the bitnami/charts repo to discuss this issue further.

Comment: Thanks. It's great if you can suggest to me other solutions.